# How to write bash script which recursively scan subdirectories and list files with current day of month?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I need to write a simple bash script to recursively scan subdirectories (starting at the current directory), listing the names of all files where the name contains the current day-of-the-month.
I am very new to bash script.

I had wrote the following script but I did not get anything.

```
  #!/bin/bash

  for i in $find*
  do
  if grep -rq date +%d $i; then
  echo $i
  fi
  done
```

Comment: `man find` and look for, for example;  `-mtime`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find`. Example:

```
find . -type f -iname "*09*"
```

`-iname "*09*"` tells it to find only files that have "09" in them. You can replace it with the day of the month that you have.

`-type f` tells it to return files only, not directories.

There are many more options. Read the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) for `find`

Answer (score 0):

Get current day in a variable using `date` command then run `find`:

```
d=$(date '+%d')

cd /base/dir
find . -name "*$d*" -type f
```